# Memory Management for Presenting and Dismissing in ARC based app

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I've facing a funny problem with my app. Some of my views contain lots of elements which make each of them something around 50MB. I've enabled ARC on my project but I do have problem with presenting and dismissing the view controllers. I believe that I'm using a wrong method.

I have 5 shortcut buttons to switch between views. And currently I'm doing it like this:

```
AboutVC *aboutview = [[AboutVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"AboutVC" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:aboutview animated:YES];
```

So every time if the user wants to go back the landing view(or switch to another view), same amount of memory(50MB) will be allocated. Hence after 4-5 times switching, the App crashes awesomely.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure you dismiss your views properly. If they are being added to any sort of collection class they must be removed from there in order for ARC's magic to kick in. You need to dismiss the modal view controller like so (from within AboutVC class): `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`.

Comment: SO You mean something like this
Go to AboutVC :
AboutVC *aboutview = [[AboutVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"AboutVC" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:aboutview animated:YES];

And from there going to another view :
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
aVC *view2 = [[aVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"view2" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:view2 animated:YES];

Am I right?

Comment: It sounds to me like you are using the modal views incorrectly... It sounds like you want to have each view navigate to the one next to it... For that you should consider using a navigation controller. Modal controllers are meant to be pushed on the navigation stack, and popped off before adding any more views.